# recent messages with firestore - 1 second document write limit - swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I would like to implement a feature in my iOS application similar to the whatsapp application, when you're in the chat view controller you can see all the users you last contacted with affiliated the last message in the chat.

In order to do that I thought about creating a collection called something like "LastMessages" structured in this way:

```
/LastMessages/userID/LastMessagesSubCollection/user1ID
```

and in this last user1ID document I store the last message present in the chat. Whenever a user sends a message I overwrite this document with the last message the users have sent.

So considering that Firestore has a `Maximum sustained write rate to a document` of `1 per second`:
Is this the wrong approach to solve this problem? If both users send 2 messages at the same exact moment there may be some problem in the document write?
What may be a better approach to solve the same problem?

Comment: I think you should be fine as long as your not constantly writing to the same document many times per second. The docs say "Sustaining a write rate above once per second increases latency and causes contention errors. This is not a hard limit, and you can surpass the limit in short bursts". If you end up running into latency/contention errors, I've seen people use the realtime database for storing realtime messages (since there's no write limitation) and using Firestore for the rest of their main documents.

Comment: The question is a little vague and you can get around the 1 per second with sharding. Also, it appears you're writing data to two different collections/documents so that would not be a conflict. If you are concerned though, encapsulate your writes in transactions. There's a whole host of options but again, the use case is kinda vague and without seeing code you're having difficulty with the question is a bit OT for SO.

Comment: @Jay thank you for your feedback, actually as Spood suggested there's no problem in overwriting the same document if OCCASIONALLY I overcome the limit of 1 time per second. So that's what I did and it seems to work fine